# Using ChangeListener for JavaFX ChoiceBox working with the String

Tags: java, string, javafx, java-8, changelistener

When using a ChangeListener added to a ChoiceBox, is there a way to access the items from the observableArrayList directly, to update for example a String type Instance variable?

I implemented this code here, which lets me work fine, with the index values of the observableArrayList. But, I am pretty new to Java so I am just wondering if that is the way to go? Or if there is a better way to update the String Instance variable with the ChangeListener.

```
cb_1.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList("High", "Average ", "Low"));
cb_1.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable,
        Number oldVal, Number newVal) {

        System.out.println(observable.getValue());              
    }
});
```

Comment: well Observablelist will auto update any Node that that is being backed by it, without the developer's effort, and yes it is the best way to do it to my intel, so yea go for it

Comment: thank you for some authority Elltz!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I solved by creating a class that implements ChangeListener, but with a ChoiceBox final field that is set in the class constructor

```
private class MyChangeListener implements ChangeListener<Number>{
    final ChoiceBox<Number> cb;

    MyChangeListener(ChoiceBox<Number> cb) {
        this.cb = cb;
     }

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
        System.out.println("cb: "+cb.getId());
    }

}
```

I used it later in the code like

```
@FXML   ChoiceBox boxValidPwd;
[..]
boxValidPwd.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(1,2,3,4,5,6));
boxValidPwd.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(new MyChangeListener(boxValidPwd));
```

and you shoud see in the output the choiceBox ID used.